# Electron load remote URL and execute javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to load a website in electron by loading an URL like this

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost/index.html')
```

but like this the javascript on the website doesn't load.
The following solution works:
Add the following code around the app.js that is loaded in the index.html

```
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
<script src="/app/app.js"></script> 
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

but is not optimal as I'm most likely not allowed to change the code of the website itself.
Are there any other options for simply wrapping a website in electron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to set `nodeIntegration` to false in your `BrowserWindow` settings. That should resolve the issue. Have a look at `webPreferences` on this page: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md

Answer (score 2):

This is just example add to Chris Riebschlager's answer.
Load google.com in main.js

```
let googleWindow;

// handle create googleWindow
function createGoogleWindow(){
    googleWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            preload:`${__dirname}/scripts/googleWindow.js`
          }});
    //load html into window
    googleWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com/');
    //garbage collection handle
    googleWindow.on('close', function(){
        googleWindow=null;
    });
}
```

Script googleWindow.js referenced above:

```
const electron = require('electron');
function search(){
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
    input.value = "test";
}

setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello");search(); }, 3000);
```

The above script alert "Hello" after 3 seconds, and enter "test" in the search box on google.com.

You can also send an event from the main process as a trigger, use the webContents of the window.

Comment: I can't even get google to open, the entire app crashes immediately as soon as the page renders.